# How to find the Cipher strngth in code?

Tags: visual-c++

i am creating a RSA key to sign some certificate like,

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider ^RSAkey = gcnew RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
```

In some other place,

```
array<System::Byte> ^somekey = gcnew array<System::Byte>(24);
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider ^des3 = gcnew TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
ICryptoTransform ^cryptor = des3->CreateEncryptor(somekey, iv);
```

Now i have to change the cipher strength to 56-bit(DES_CBC_SHA).
Which one i have to change?